# How to keep only a module (Canny Edge Detection) of opencv android library?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, android-ndk, canny-operator

I am currently working on an **android** app which involves the **Canny Edge Detection**. I decided to use the **opencv** library which is much faster than using Java. So I placed the **libopencv_java.so** files in their respective directories. It worked but it resulted in **huge apk size**. I don't know much of C++ language. Is it possible to generate the libopencv_java.so file which include only the required components for edge detection in order to reduce the apk size?

If yes, how?

Otherwise please suggest other fast and smaller libraries to perform Canny Edge Detection in android.

Comment: Implement it yourself?

Comment: opencv is open source so you can modify it. You'll need some core functionality in addition to canny. Take care of license stuff.

Comment: @Micka thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is that the library is so huge. I cannot modify it. I don't know how to build only a specific part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build lib for android using the method mentioned here.

https://zami0xzami.wordpress.com/2016/03/17/building-opencv-for-android-from-source/

I guess you are using JNI to implement you work and you must be using opencv-Android-sdk.

1. If you are using static library copy only required lib to../OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk1/sdk/native/libs/(Target-abi folder).

   2.If you are using shared one then you will need libopencv_java.So for reducing the size, remove unrequired lib from libopencv_java.so.To remove this lib go to /opencv/modules/MODULE_NAME/CMakeLists.txt
   find a line 
   ocv_define_module(imgproc opencv_core WRAP java python)
   and remove java from this line.

As far I know canny edge is a part of either imgproc or core or highgui. So modify cmakelists of all modules except these. Now build lib using the method in link (given at the starting of post).Copy new  lib to sdk folder.

Comment: The method described in the website is too complex; couldn't figure it out. Anyway thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Are you stuck at any specific part?? I  have the same method in my case, It worked. Which part is complex??

Comment: Finally, I am able to get rid of lib_opencv_java.so using static libraries :D

Comment: @GarvitaTiwari I am unable to use by 1st option you specified.